# Turning adjective+すぎる into adverbs

Tags: english-to-japanese, adverbs

Suppose I want to say

> "He was taken from us too soon."

Could I do this by using 早い->早すぎる->早すぎて and writing the sentence this way?

> 彼は、私達から、早すぎて奪われました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-過ぎて does not work adverbially like this. 過ぎる must attach the modified verb part.

- 急いで食べ過ぎですよ。
  You're eating too fast.
  <sub>(Not: You're overeating in a hurry.)</sub>
- 甘く煮過ぎています。
  You have sweetened it too much (while cooking it).
  <sub>(Not: You have overcooked it.)</sub>
- 彼女は遅く来過ぎた。
  She arrived too late.

Therefore, if you mean "He died too early" and want to use 過ぎる, the grammatically correct sentence is 彼は早く死に過ぎました, though this doesn't sound very polite. I think a natural option is 彼はあまりに早く私達を残してこの世を去りました or something. For this meaning, forget the verb 奪う.

Answer (score 0):

If "was taken from us" mean "died, 奪われた is not common word for it.
However, These are OK.

彼は、私達から、あまりにも早く奪われました。
彼は、私達から、とても早く奪われました。
彼が、私達から、奪われたのは、早すぎました。

彼は、私達から、早すぎて奪われました。 means He was taken from us because something was too soon.